# Unknow error uploading generating video thumbnail via PHP-FFMpeg

Tags: raspbian, php, ffmpeg

I'm running Rasbian os + PHP 7.3 on Nginx and I'm facing a problem when uploading and generating a thumbnail of a video file. I have FFMpeg on my OS, I chmod 777 the folders, I even visudo and added permition to www-data /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg and /usr/local/bin/ffprobe but nothing works.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php' ;

if($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] != '')
{
 $data = explode(".", $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
 $extension = $data[1];
 $allowed_extension = array("mp4");
 if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))
 {
  $name_only = pathinfo($_FILES["upload_file"]['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME) ; // Main Name Only 
  $new_video_name = $name_only.'.mp4';
  $new_img_name = $name_only.'.jpg';

  $path = $_POST["hidden_folder_name"] .'/'. $new_video_name;
  $img_path = $_POST["hidden_folder_name"] .'/'.$new_img_name ;
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $path))
  {

    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, 
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,  
    'temporary_directory' => '/var/ffmpeg-tmp'
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($path);
    $video->filters()->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 180))->synchronize();
    $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(2))->save($img_path);

   echo 'FILE UPLOADED';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'THERE IS AN ERROR';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'INVALID FILE';
 }
}
else
{
 echo 'PLEASE SELECT FILE';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figure it out.

```
    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, 
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12, 
));
```